# How to find in java in this statement line number?

Tags: java

I want to find the line number of a code dynamically. How can this be done?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("This Line Number is : ????");
 }
```

Comment: In general the use of a logger is preferable: `Logger.getAnonymousLogger().log(Level.INFO, "some message");` The format in general contains class name and method, but line number is no problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get line number from `getStackTrace()[]`

```
 public static void main(String[] arg)
 {

     System.out.println("This Line Number is : "+Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getLineNumber());
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it compulsory to use your own log functions? It will be easier to use log4j or any other "standard" log libray